# Underscore and bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, underscore.js, datetimepicker

I am trying to get bootstrap datetimepicker to work from https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker on my webapp. Due to the fact that I am using templates, I cant have the script tags needed to initialize the datetimepicker inside the template script tags.

```
         $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker(); //where should this go
         <script type="text/template" id="manage-todos-template">
         <div id="user-info">
         Signed in as <%= Parse.User.current().get("username") %> (<a href="#"       class="log-out">Log out</a>)
         </div>
         <br>
         <div>
         <textarea name="styled-textarea" maxlength="50" id="styled" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');" onblur="setbg('white')">Enter promo here    </textarea>
         </div> 
         <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
         <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="form-group">
         <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">     </span>
          </span>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <button href="#" class="submitPromo">Submit</button>
          </script>


  //render

  render: function() {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your are rendering your template withing some view, initialize the datepicker in your render method after you render the template.

Comment: Ive tried that but I get Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Where? It would be helpful if you include your render code, or better yet a jsbin or jsfiddle.

Comment: I have edited my post with the render function for manage-todos-template

Comment: Where are you rendering your html? is that part of a different view?

Comment: Yes it is part of a different view.

Comment: It sounds like either the script isn't loaded yet, can you create a jsbin or jsfiddle that illustrates your issue?

Comment: Can I upload files, like datetimepicker.js? Or else how can I reproduce the issue?

Comment: You should be able to link to the file under GitHub and for the rest of the scripts you might want to have a look at http://cdnjs.com/

Comment: There also seems to be a bootstrap-datepicker on cdnjs, but I'm not sure if it is the same one or not.

Comment: I was not able to link... but here you can see my code

Comment: You seemed to have left out the relevant parts from your fiddle (I don't see the anything with your timepicker's id there... Anyway Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qulibavi/1/) that shows you how to render a template and then initialize the datetimepicker on it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just wasnt finding the date time picker correctly, this.$el.find('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

Comment: Is there any way I can give you some points? Sorry I am new to stack

Comment: The reason you couldn't find it is probably because at that point it wasn't yet attached to the `DOM`. I'll write up my comments as an answer.

Comment: Yes makes so much sense now. I thought since I rendered the html which contained the datetimepicker, I didn't need to attach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern where you need to initialize some third part component on top of your rendered html. What you basically need to do is first render your HTML and then call your third party component on the appropriate element. Keep in mind that if you haven't yet attached your view's element to the DOM (as is often the case when you are rendering a view) you can still traverse it's `el` using `$el.find`.

For example

```
 render: function () {

    var template = _.template($('#mytemplate').html());

    this.$el.html(template);
    this.$el.find('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    return this;
  }
```

And a link to a [sjbin](http://jsbin.com/qulibavi/1/)